# What do you get when you pull the Bruhat Decomposition back to the Lie algebra via the exponential map?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, algebraic-combinatorics

If $G$ is a connected, reductive, complex group with Borel subgroup $B < G$ and Weyl group $W$, we can write

$$G = \bigsqcup_{w \in W} B w B$$

If $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G$, we have an exponential map $\exp : \mathfrak{g} \to G$, so we get a decomposition

$$\mathfrak{g} = \bigsqcup_{w \in W} \exp^{-1}(B w B).$$

Does this accomplish anything?  Has it been studied?

Comment: Any updates on this problem? It seems interesting.